# bind socket fails with errno 88

Tags: c++, sockets, serversocket

I was searching for an answer for my issue though nothing relevant came up.
I'm writing a very simple code for running a server on a virtual machine (VBOX) running ubuntu 14.04.

I turned off my firewall and my anti-virus program (read that it might be related)

I rechecked (and looked for different ports) that the port is not in use but keep on receiving return value of -1 to the bind() function with errno 88 (socket operation on non-socket).

I'm running the server on port 7777.
Also tried running this code on my host

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

p.s also checked the code with valgrind for memory leaks but it looks fine.

the code is as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_OF_THREADS  3

static int  connFd;

void *task1(void *);

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int pid, portNo, listenFd;
    socklen_t len; // store the size of the address
    bool loop = false;
    struct sockaddr_in svrAdd, clntAdd;

    pthread_t threadArr[NUM_OF_THREADS];

    if (argc < 2){
        cerr << "ERROR: ./server <port>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    portNo = atoi(argv[1]); // TODO verify the port is between 1024 and 65535

    //Create the socket
    if (listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0){
        cerr << "ERROR: cannot open socket." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char*)&svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

    svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

    cout << "port number is : " << portNo << endl;

    //bind socket
    int bound = bind(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));
    if ( bound < 0 ){
        cerr << "ERROR: cannot bind, error number: " << errno << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    listen(listenFd, 5);

    len = sizeof(clntAdd);

    int noTread = 0;

    while(noTread < 3){
        cout << "Listening..." << endl;

       if (connFd = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAdd, &len)<0){
            cerr << "ERROR: cannot accept connection" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Connection successful" << endl;
        }

        pthread_create(&threadArr[noTread], NULL, task1, NULL);
        noTread++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_join(threadArr[i], NULL);
    }
    /*int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen, n;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) <  0){
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr - INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&))*/

    return 0;
}

void *task1(void *dummyPt){
    cout << "Thread number:  " << pthread_self() << endl;
    char test[300];
    bzero(test, 301);
    bool loop = false;
    while (!false){
        bzero(test, 301);
        read(connFd, test, 300);
        string tester(test);
        cout << "\n\t\t TESTER = " << tester << endl;

        if(tester == "exit"){
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Closing thread and conn" << endl;
    close(connFd);
}
```

The output of the execution:

ERROR: cannot bind, error number: 88
port number is : 7777

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 162ms)

Please help, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0){
```

Precedence problem. The result of this condition is to assign zero or 1 to `listenFd.` Try this:

```
if ((listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
```

Comment: Thank you!!! that's working now should have seen it myself